# SQL Find/Ignore invalid date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I am using SQL Server.

From each row, I take day and month values from the fields c.daybirth,c.monthbirth
and the year from getdate(), and I want to have a field that shows if this date is valid or not (invalid example: 31 February)

I have created this solution:

```
case day(dateadd(month,c.monthbirth-1,dateadd(day,c.daybirth-1,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))) when c.daybirth then 1 else 0 end
```

which works, but I find it hard to read. Is there a smarter alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can do:

```
where try_convert(date,
                  datefromparts(year(getdate()), c.monthbirth, c.daybirth)
                 ) is not null
```

EDIT:

Amusing.  This is better:

```
where try_convert(date,
                  cast(year(getdate()) * 10000 + c.monthbirth * 100 + c.daybirth as varchar(255))
                 ) is not null
```

Comment: This won't run, as datefromparts already throws an error. However, if I I replace datefromparts with an appropriate string, I can get what you want. Thanks.

Comment: Code: try_convert(date,convert(nvarchar,c.daybirth)+'-'+convert(nvarchar,c.monthbirth)+'-'+convert(nvarchar,year(getdate())),103)